# C program : print in text file 2 numbers in row

Tags: c, file, numbers, row

I need c program that save numbers it txt file, but numbers must be 2 in row. 
For now I have this code, but how to print numbers 2 in row.
I really hope that someone can help me for that problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define max 80
#define n 30
#define space ' '
void inputText(char text[][max], int *len);
void writeText(FILE *fp, char *text);
int main(){
    char text[n][max];
    int i=0, len=0; 
    FILE *fp=NULL;
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    inputText (text,&len);
    fp=fopen("test.txt", "a");
    if(fp!=NULL)
    for (i=0;i<len;i++)
    writeText (fp, text[i]);
    else
    printf("Error!");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
void inputText(char text[][max], int *len)
{   char ch;
    int i=0, s=0;
printf("Input text:");
while ((gets(text[i]))!=NULL)
{       i++;
    (*len)++;
}
}
void writeText(FILE *fp, char *text)
{ fputs(text,fp);
  fprintf(fp,"\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps change the function writeText to something like this

```
void writeText(FILE *fp, char *text, int current)
{ fputs(text,fp);
  if(current % 2 == 0)
  {
      fprintf(fp,"\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Without changing the number of paramerters to writeText, you could define a static variable inside writeText and only output an "\n" when it is true, then variable = !variable, before the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The `fprintf(fp,"\n");` statement (inside `writeText()`) is what makes the line breaks in your output. You should figure out a way to run that statement only after the 2nd, 4th, 6th, ... number output.